# I'm unable to start the GCE instance "zone ... does not have enough resources"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm unable to start the google cloud instance:

```
Starting VM instance "am01" failed. Error: The zone 'projects/.../zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at **the cause of this issue**:

1. When you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory.
2. When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message:

   ```
   Error: The zone 'projects/imposing-fin-273614/zones/asia-south1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
   ```

   more information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

   > If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
   >   or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
   >   resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
   >   request. This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
   >   and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.
3. Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve your issue**:

1. Move your instance to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) by following [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).
2. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future:

   > Create reservations for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific
   >   zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without
   >   additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for
   >   your workloads when you need them. After you create a reservation, you
   >   begin paying for the reserved resources immediately, and they remain
   >   available for your project to use indefinitely, until the reservation
   >   is deleted.

Comment: Adding this for the reservation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources